# Chain rule: abstract exercise

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Let $z = \phi(u,v),u = f(x,y), v = g(x,y)$ with $\phi, f, g$ infinitely smooth. Suppose
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$.
Prove the following equalities:

$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} =
\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial y^2}
$$

and
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \hat{\phi}}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \hat{\phi}}{\partial y^2} = \left[ \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)^2 \right] \left[ \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial u^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial v^2} \right]
$$

with $\hat{\phi} = \phi(f(x,y), g(x,y))$.

I think I managed to prove the first equality, I just worked with each side of the equality and used $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$. This, together with the Schwarz Theorem for change the order of derivation, allowed me to conclude that both sides of the first equality are $0$, and in particular, are equal.

However, for the second equality, I am not quite sure about what to do. I know from the Chain Rule that $\frac{\partial \hat{\phi}}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} +  \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$, and the same for variable $y$. But I don't know how to continue. The exercises I have done previously involved concrete functions, maybe I just have a bad day, but I'm feeling lost. Can you help?

Comment: In the first sentence, you wrote $u = f(u, v)$. Did you mean to write $u = f(x, y)$?

Comment: @SammyBlack Yes, I will edit it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed it! The key was noting that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u}\right) = \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial u^2} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial u\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$. This allow us to compute the second partial derivatives of $\phi$ using the product rule. The rest is just calculations using the first equality for simplifying terms and the hypothesis at the very end.

Comment: $\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u}\right) = \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial u^2} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial u\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, I made the computations again and was able to get the result, thought the intermediates steps were longer this time.